# How to optimize the construction of the following dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hello I have two arrays that look as follows:

```
print("list of clusters",y_pred[:10]
print("list of comments",listComments[:10])
```

output:

```
list of comments ['hello This', 'Fabiola hello', 'I am using',  ...

list of clusters [ 2 11  2  2 11  2  2  2  2  2]
```

the list of clusters is was builded applying kmeans to every comment of the "list of comments" so this two list have the same length:

```
y_pred = kmeans.predict(tfidf)
print("length list comments",len(listComments))
print("length list clusters",len(y_pred))
```

output:

```
length list comments 17223
length list clusters 17223
```

Then I  would like to group all the comments that belong a specific number for instance to create a dictionary with the number of cluster as key and as the list of all the comments that belongs to this specific cluster, as follows:

```
myDict = {2: ['hello This', 'I am using',...], 11: ['Fabiola hello', ...], ... }
```

for this example since the first label of cluster is 2, the first comment is assigned to my dictionary and then since the label is 11 in the list of clusters the following comment is assigned to the cluster 11 then the label is 2 thus the comment 'I am using' is assigned to the list of cluster 2:

I tried to achieve this as follows:

```
dict_clusters2 = {}
for i in range(0,len(y_pred)):
    #print(kmeans.labels_[i])
    #print(listComments[i])
    if not y_pred[i] in dict_clusters2:
        dict_clusters2[y_pred[i]] = []
    dict_clusters2[y_pred[i]].append(listComments[i])
print("dictionary constructed")
```

however this approach is taking a lot of time to compute for that reason I would like to appreciate a suggestion to optimize this process, thanks a lot for the attention and support,

the version of python that I am using is the following:

```
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
3.5.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a lot of indexing for both lists which its complexity is O(N) and some other operations. Instead, you can use `zip` function in order to create a generator contains pairs of numbers and comments then use `collections.defaultdict()` in order to create your expected dictionary (which your case is exactly what this function is for):

```
from collections import defaultdict
pairs = zip(y_pred, listComments)

dict_clusters2 = defaultdict(list)

for num, comment in pairs:
    dict_clusters2[num].append(comment)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, however I am getting an error what would be the parameter 'list' ? this is the error that I am getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acamagon/CleanFile.py", line 133, in <module>
    dict_clusters2 = defaultdict(list)
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: @neo33 It seems that you've shadowed the built-in name `list` maybe by using it as the name of a variable. If it's so please correct that.

Comment: @ Kasramvd, yes I used that name for other list but is fixed thanks a lot for your support and complexity explantion.